# Generate sequential numbers in first column based on value in other column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm having a problem implementing a spreadsheet with several sheets that use data registered continuously on the first.

I found a solution with this script on the forum but I don't know how to edit, I'm a newbie using scripts. It makes a counter in cell T1, every time I edit something he assigns a fixed, sequential number in column A, A2:A1001 called ID. It works for all the cells I edit on every sheets of the spreadsheet. I want it to only work on the first sheet, the numbers appearing in column A, A2:A1001 depending on when I check "OK" in the corresponding cell in column C, C2:C1001, in any order: I mark "OK" in C3, it puts 1 in A3 , mark "OK" in C129, he puts 2 in A129.

Sorry for my English, is not my native language.

```
function onEdit(e) 

{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();

   var bugCount = sheet.getRange("T1").getValue();
   bugCount++;

   if (sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue() == "") {
      sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(bugCount);
      sheet.getRange("T1").setValue(bugCount);    
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should spend some time learning the JavaScript pretty basics like *literals*, *primitives*, *objects* *variables*, *operators*, *functions* among other basic stuff.

Regarding the specifics of Google Apps Script, `onEdit` is a simple trigger and i has a related *event object*. In your code the *on edit event object* is assigned to the variable `e`. This *event object* has the property `range` having assigned a *Class Range* object corresponding to the edited range. Using the *event object* instead of methods like `getActiveCell()` helps to prevent some know issues.

Considering the above, instead of

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

use

```
var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
```

instead of

```
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
```

use

```
var row = e.range.rowStart;
```

To know if the sheet of the edited range is the first sheet, you might use

```
if(sheet.getName() === e.source.getSheets()[0].getName()){
  // do something
} else {
  return; // only needed if there are more code lines for this function below this line
}
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I started looking for the topics to improve skills for future projects that need script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scripts like this, follow Rubén's advice and learn about scripting before you start copy-pasting code.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Here is an example of how to detect the sheet, column and value.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetsToWatch = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  const valueToWatch = /^(OK)$/i;
  const columnToWatch = 3; // column C
  const columnToStamp = 1; // column A
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const idNumberCell = sheet.getRange('T1');
  if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch
    || !e.value.match(valueToWatch)
    || !sheet.getName().match(sheetsToWatch)
    || sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp).getDisplayValue()) {
    return;
  }
  const idNumber = (Number(idNumberCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1;
  idNumberCell.setValue(idNumber);
  sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp).setValue(idNumber);
}
```